# What is a good api for mapping gps coordinates in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, gps, gis

I have a project that has a list of gps coordinates. I would like to find a way to make a simple map of those coordinates (possibly just one at a time). The map should have basic street info.

This part of our project is pretty simple so I don't think it needs to be an exceptionally feature rich product. This also means it shouldn't be really expensive.

What is a good product to achieve this?

edit: This is a desktop app where internet connectivity will probably not be available.

Comment: What's your target output platform?

Comment: if internet isn't available how to do you expect to generate the map? Store the entire earth map within the application?

Comment: It is for a windows xp/vista machine. 
I've gotten the impression that basic street maps of the US can be relatively small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Maps is great for this.

If this is a desktop app with internet access you could still host an IE control and show it there.

EDIT: If this is a desktop app without internet access you'll have to buy something like Microsoft Streets & Trips. I don't know if it has reusable controls. You probably have to buy something more expensive to get that. Applications of this nature often fall under the category "GIS". Try searching Google for that.

Answer (score 1):

[Sharpmap](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap) is open source project written in C# and released under LGPL. To quote first line from page:

> SharpMap is an easy-to-use mapping library for use in web and desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this solution

- Map Rendering: [SharpMap](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap)
- Geometry operations: [NetTopologySuite](http://code.google.com/p/nettopologysuite/)
- Map data store: shapefiles in your file system or [PostGis](http://postgis.refractions.net/) over [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)
- Map data itself: the easiest way may be extracting from [OpenStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data. [Here](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/), for example you can download shapefiles for your desired location

Everyting is open source (more or less, check the licenses) and works fine on windows.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has an API. They have [javascript](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm), [silverlight,wpf](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/samples/start.htm), and [flash](http://mapapps.esri.com/serverdemos/FlexViewer/index.html). they may have more.  ESRI is pretty much the standard in mapping.